# Use PHP to deploy 15 minutes trial VPS powered by Scaleway

Tags: php, vps

i just knew thats the http://instantcloud.io api link is https://try.cloud.online.net

and i want to provide free 15 minutes VPS to my site visitors to enjoy more , ***of course i will leave credits to the instantcloud.io*** becoz they are the hosters

can someone tell me some php examples to start building?

Comment: Asking for tutorials/examples is explicitly off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: to correct you, Instantcloud.io was giving 20 minutes trial in the past but now it's only 15 minutes.**

---

Seems really simple.

Anyway, the **Instantcloud.io** API link is https://try.cloud.online.net/servers and not https://try.cloud.online.net .

And as a lot of APIs, the Instantcloud.io API return the data using JSON.

Currently, I get the **following** when I try to browse https://try.cloud.online.net/servers in the browser:

```
{
  "message": "No server available at the moment",
  "type": "unknown_resource"
}
```

And when I try to click "***GET YOUR C2M SERVER***" button in http://instantcloud.io/, I get

> **Oops!**
>
> All cloud servers are busy, please retry in few minutes :)

So, https://try.cloud.online.net/servers really return the correct answer!

---

Start by making the PHP part like that:

```
<?php
$instantcloud['api'] = "https://try.cloud.online.net/servers";
$instantcloud['jsonfalse'] = json_decode($instantcloud['api']);
if( $instantcloud['jsonfalse']->message == "No server available at the moment" ) {
    echo 'Failed creating server. Reason: no stocks available.';
    die();
}
?>
```

I really don't know how we can create the server AT THE MOMENT , because I get "No server available at the moment" and I don't know what the API will return if the server is created...

***So wait until I'm able to create a server then I'll edit this answer!***

Comment: i never thought someone will give really great explaination like that !!! +1 +1 +1 +1

Comment: @usamember - Thank you but, if you used Google before asking this question you was going to done your job more faster.

All what you have to know, is how to convert JSON from URL to **$var->param** and this can be done by using **json_decode();**